# VB6 in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vb6

Is it possible to create a VB6 application in Visual Studio 2010 for creating COM applications?

Answer (score 19):

No, this is not possible.  VB6 application cannot be created in any version of Visual Studio beyond Visual Studio 6.0 SP6.

You can, however, write assemblies in .Net (any version) that are "Com visible."

You can set an assembly as "Com Visible" by checking the "Make COM Visible" checkbox on the project settings dialog in whichever version of Visual Studio (that supports .Net) you choose.

Comment: Aren't all VS .net projects COM-visible by default?  (i've yet to have to care, and i seem to remember .net being the "new COM" or something.)

Comment: No, they're not COM-visible by default.  I think making them COM-visible requires updating the registry, and that's something that .Net tries hard to steer you away from.

Comment: .Net is not the "new COM" at all, and actually uses COM all over the place internally since so much of Windows is COM-based.

Comment: Unfortunately, when you are opening something like Outlook with .Net and setting various properties for the first time - its performance is extremely slow. We have done this in VS 2010 in C#, and it takes almost 20 seconds to open. It must do this in 3 seconds.